# saving file in a folder

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, file

In my MVC application am allowing the user to create a new PDF file using editor. I want to save the created file in the folder how can i do so?
This is my view code:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="message" ></textarea>
<input class="green_button" id="btnCre" type="button" text="Save" value="Save" onclick="confirmsave();"/>
function confirmsave() {
    var box = dhtmlx.modalbox({
        title: "PDF File Details",

        text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div><label> Enter The File Name <input id='fileName' class='inform' type='text'></label><br></div><div><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='save' onclick='create_PDF(this)' style='width:80px;'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='closeFile(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div></div>",
        width: "300px"
    });
}
function closeFile(box) {

    dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);


}
function create_PDF(box) {
      var fileName = $("#fileName").val();
    var content = CKEDITOR.instances["message"].getData();
    if (content == "") {
        alert("Enter Content in The Editor");
        return false;
    }
    dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
    dhtmlx.message("Saving file...");
    $.post("/CreatePDF/CreatePDFile",
    {
        content: '' + content + ''
    }, function (data) {

             data = jQuery.trim(data);
            alert("PDF File created succesfully");
            //$("#display_thumbs").html(data);
            CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].setData("");


        });
    }
```

and Controller code is

```
public ActionResult CreatePDFile(FormCollection data)
    {
        var htmlContent = data["content"];
        var fileName = data["fileName"];

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The eaiest way is to use a php pdf creator in which u cqn create a pdf from the data provided. Have a look at tcpdf and see if that would work

Comment: Am using CKEDITOR to do so and have refined the code
public ActionResult CreatePDFile(FormCollection data)
        {
            var htmlContent = data["content"];
            var filename = data["filename"];
            string sFilePath = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + filename + ".pdf");        
            return View();
        }
but now am getting error for filename. When i debug it shows filename value undefined

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting the content as part of a JSON object it's easier to post it as part of a form.  See [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for more detail on what you need to do.

Comment: In this part of code am not allowing the user to upload the files infact using CKEDITOR user can create his/her own PDF file. I got half of the solution as follows
public ActionResult CreatePDFile(FormCollection data)
        {
            var htmlContent = data["content"];
            var filename = data["filename"];
            string sFilePath = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + filename + ".pdf");        
            return View();
        }
but now am getting error for filename. When i debug it shows filename value undefined

Comment: I got the answer for the above problem

    public ActionResult CreatePDFile(FormCollection data)
        {
            var htmlContent = data["content"];
            var filename = data["filename"];
            string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/pdf/" + filename + ".html");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sFilePath))
            {

                FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(sFilePath);
                
                return View();
            }
now file is getting saved but problem is its showing size of file as 0kb even if i enter the data in it and can't open that file

Comment: Well it looks like you're only creating the file.  You still need to use a StreamWriter to actually write the binary data in the content to the file after you've created it.